# Ubuntu 14.04.1 Audio Crashes After Using Hydrogen Drum Machine App

Tags: sound, alsa, ubuntu-studio

Basically I can play all audio, from system startup, but after using Hydrogen drum app, I can no longer playback any audio, or videos. Any help?

Comment: Try to choose "Alsa" as a sounddriver in the preferences dialog!

Comment: @mauser doesn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command at terminal or run via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to reload sound drivers. Then audio works again.

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this worked for me. In Hydrogen Drum Machine go to Tools -> Preferences. Then select Audio System. The first option has Auto, Jack, Alsa and PortAudio in the drop down menu, select PortAudio here. Click on Ok. Again click Ok when asked to restart Audio drivers.

I needed to restart Hydrogen once when the audio had crashed/frozen and it was fine afterwards.